# Some products cant be added to cart since Magento2.3.3

Tags: magento2

We have upgraded Magento2.3.3, some products are throwing the error :

> Product that you are trying to add is not available.

I have looked online and saw something about a view called `Inventory_stock_1`, It exists already and I cannot figure out why my product wont add.

Here is an image of a list of products that wont add to cart (except the first one, that works)

[image]

Has anyone had this since the new update?

Comment: You have no `Product Salable Quantity`.

Comment: Other products that work dont have this

Comment: Have you face this problem in configurable products only?

Comment: yeah just them products so far

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Just to test saleble is there any way to edit this hard like in a table so i can test if that is the issue?

Comment: First try to execute `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and clear cache.

Comment: done that, no ch ange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103604/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-gaz-smith).

Comment: @DhadukMitesh Do you know why this happened? your sql and re-index worked but im worried about new products and it happening again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, take a backup of the `inventory_source_item` table.

Now execute below SQL query in MySQL,

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `inventory_source_item` (source_code, sku, quantity, status)
select 'default', sku, qty, stock_status from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` as `lg` join `catalog_product_entity` as `prd` on((`lg`.`product_id` = `prd`.`entity_id`)))
```

Execute the below command.

- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

And check it.

Comment: Hi this worked for me, do you know why this happened? and how i can prevent it from happening again?

Comment: works for me as well I am adding product via rest API